# Unable to Update One to One Django Models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm using the default Django 'User' model to create a user. After successful creation, this user is directed to a profile page where they are asked to fill up their profile. The profile, or the `Profile` model has a `OneToOneField` with `User`. On the first save, the profile is successful because the first insert is with the `request.user` and the profile object had yet to be created.

On future attempts to edit this form, I get an error that says

> return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
>   sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   app_profile.user_id The above exception was the direct cause of the
>   following exception: . . return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query,
>   params) django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   app_profile.user_id [26/Jun/2018 06:32:51] "POST /profile/ HTTP/1.1"
>   500 162255

Here is my `Profile` model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(choices=(
        ('content-creator', 'Content Creator'),
        ('artist', 'Artist'),
    ), max_length=20)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    youtube = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    instagram = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    facebook = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    twitter = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    other = models.TextField(null=True, max_length=100, blank=True)
```

And here is the `Profile` view

```
class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'

    form_class = ProfileForm
    template_name = 'app/profile.html'
    initial = {}

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        if profile:
            form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
        else:
            form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile_obj = form.save(commit=False)
            profile_obj.user = request.user
            profile_obj.save()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

What am I doing wrong with my logic? I think this should be pretty straightforward to deal with but I can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont pass `instance` argument to the form in `post()` method. Without it Django trying to create new object on every `POST` request.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
    if profile: 
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
    else:
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        profile_obj = form.save(commit=False)
        profile_obj.user = request.user
        profile_obj.save()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: Ah perfect. I was doing that in the get method, but missed it here. Thanks!